# symfony 2.4 can't get the doctrine channel in prod environment

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, monolog

I can't manage to get a log of the doctrine channel in my prod environment.

I'm using

- symfony/symfony                      v2.4.6
- symfony/monolog-bundle               v2.6.0
- doctrine/common                      v2.4.2

Here is my monolog config in `config_prod.yml`:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        doctrine:
            bubble: false
            action_level: DEBUG
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_doctrine.log"
            channels: doctrine
        security:
            bubble: false
            action_level: DEBUG
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_security.log"
            channels: security
        request:
            bubble: false
            action_level: DEBUG
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%_request.log"
            channels: request
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: ["!doctrine", "!security", "!request"]
```

Here is my whole doctrine config in `config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

I have the 3 files

```
../../../logs/prod.log
../../../logs/prod_request.log
../../../logs/prod_security.log
```

I can't manage to get `prod_doctrine.log`.

I tried all the channels in the same file `prod.log`. I had all channels alright, except doctrine...

What can prevent the logging of doctrine? Is there some incompatibility with my versions?

Comment: Can you please show what your `doctrine.dbal.logging` config value is?

Comment: Sure. I edited my question. `doctrine.dbal.logging` is not configured.

Comment: Ok, I see where that's leading. `kernel.debug` is set to false in prod environment. Since `doctrine.dbal.logging` is equal to `kernel.debug` by default, it's set to false...

Comment: Thank you. Setting `doctrine.dbal.logging` to true works. Please add an anwser so I can award you the bounty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `doctrine.dbal.logging` to `true` to enable production doctrine logging.

Comment: See official documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration